# read subcollection in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I read subcollections in firestore?

```
db.collection('users')
  .doc('5mmwJba8FVMrdHGOPBYraOQzDe22')
  .collection('restaurants').get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
```

and the path is: `/users/5mmwJba8FVMrdHGOPBYraOQzDe22/restaurants/qZg6gkOvYHOPXHDJAqBF`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add `doc('qZg6gkOvYHOPXHDJAqBF')` after your `collection('restaurants')` like so:

```
db.collection('users').doc('5mmwJba8FVMrdHGOPBYraOQzDe22')
  .collection('restaurants').doc('qZg6gkOvYHOPXHDJAqBF').get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: And if I dont know the ID of the first collection? Where you write `5mmwJba8FVMrdHGOPBYraOQzDe22` i need to leave it empty, I need all the subcollections of each doc in the main collection. Something like `db.collection('users').doc().collection("restaurants").get()`